# iOS Subclassing from single nib file and inheritance of IBOutlet connections

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, xib, subclassing

I'm really really new to iOS programming in particular and MVC programming in general.

I have a project which uses a single nib for multiple subclasses (all of the base class that the nib was originally created for). The nib just contains a collection of buttons stored in an IBOutlet connection. I want the buttons to show and do different things when clicked depending on which subclass is referencing the nib.

Say, for instance I have a base class called BaseClassViewController, with a nib BaseClassViewController.xib which has one property

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *buttonCollection
```

Now I have a subclass called SubClassViewController which is a subclass of base class.

My question is if I call in an instance of the SubClassViewController [super initWithNibName:@"BaseClassViewController" bundle:nil], the right nib is loaded. Do I also inherit the IBOutletCollection property of the base class and all the connections between the collection and the .xib of the base class?

If not, is there a way to do this for a single xib without creating a new property in the subclass and reestablishing connections with the xib for the subclass? This would seem to defeat the purpose of inheritance in this simplified example.

My ultimate goal is to have the buttons do different things when clicked in different phases of the app. One possibility that I was thinking of is to create some kind of property in a single view controller that will determine what clicking will do, something like:

```
-(IBAction) buttonClicked:(UIButton)sender{ 
    if([modeString isEqualToString:@"Mode1"]){
        \\Do something
    }
    ...
 }
```

but this is very organization unfriendly and I wanted to have other methods for each subclassed view controller. Is there a better way for this than subclassing? Should I just have a different nib for each subclass even though they would be the same for each? Should I do something else?